# Diretório de pastas do Windows

Tags: delphi, object-pascal, delphi-10

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que referencia diretórios locais em meu computador. Se eu tento rodar a aplicação em outro computador, as referências se perdem.

```
nmArquivo := 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\Img.txt';
nmArquivoImgAtual := 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\ImgAtual.txt';
MinutoAtual := 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\MinutoAtual.txt';
HoraAtual := 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\HoraAtual.txt';
```

Bom eu gostaria de tornar os diretórios independentes de máquinas, dinâmicos, como uma forma de encontrar os arquivos a partir de um ponto de referência.

Comment: tenta colocar no C:\seuprogama\..vai ser padrão para todos os computadores

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel, nem todo munto tem um usuário `Admin`, normalmente as pessoas tem no seu Windows um usuário com o seu nome, então no momento que você fixou o caminho `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\` só vai funcionar para quem tiver o logado como usuário `Admin`.

Uma alternativa é você usar a variável de ambiente `userprofile`, como mostro do exemplo

```
    userProfile := GetEnvironmentVariable('userprofile');
    nmArquivo := userProfile +'\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\Img.txt';
    nmArquivoImgAtual := userProfile + '\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\ImgAtual.txt';
    MinutoAtual := userProfile + '\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\MinutoAtual.txt';
    HoraAtual := userProfile + '\Desktop\Protetor de Tela\HoraAtual.txt';
```

Com essa abordagem o teu sistema fica independente de usuário logado, não precisando fixar um caminho único, podendo sempre buscar da pasta do perfil do usuário logado.

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel, você pode utilizar o `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` para retornar o diretório atual que seu sistema está instalado, dessa forma ele funcionará para qualquer computador que você utilizar.

Exemplo:

```
mApplicationPath := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);

nmArquivo := mApplicationPath + 'Img.txt';
nmArquivoImgAtual := mApplicationPath + 'ImgAtual.txt';
MinutoAtual := mApplicationPath + 'MinutoAtual.txt';
HoraAtual := mApplicationPath + 'HoraAtual.txt';
```